# Как использовать js в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Есть код в js файле:

```
// Session ID
var hfSessionId = $('[id*=hfSessionId]').val();
// User Id
var hfUserId = $('[id*=hfUserId]').val();
```

Он работает. Я же пишу в TypeScript в VisualStudio. Как мне написать аналогичный код? Компилятор ругается на знак $.
Я пробовал делать так:

```
module GameVals {
  // Session ID
  export var hfSessionId: any = $('[id*=hfSessionId]').val();
  // User Id
  export var hfUserId: any = $('[id*=hfUserId]').val();
}
```

Ругается "Cannot find name '$'" и не компилит.
Как решить проблему?
Нужно делать отдельный файл js для этого кода и как-то обращаться к нему из ts?
Или нужно как-то проигнорировать ошибку компилятора?
Или я пишу не правильно? Вроде как можно писать js код прямо в ts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` - это явно что-то из JQuery, а его нужно подключить. Например, так:

```
npm install --save jquery
npm install --save-dev -g typings
typings install --save --global dt~jquery.
```

После файл `typings/index.d.ts` нужно добавить для компиляции в tsconfig.json.

Comment: [в Typescript 2 можно еще `@type`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Comment: да, jQuery подключено. Т.е. если я подключу это библу в ts, то ошибки на $ не будет?

Comment: Да, ошибки не будет, так как транслятор tsc будет знать о такой функции и её типе.